# How to handle chrome.debugger.attach errors?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging

In my extension I'm trying to attach [debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/debugger/#method-attach) for given tabId, Here is my code

```js
if(!attachedTabIds.includes(tabId)) {
    chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId: tabId }, version, function(){
        ...
    })
}
```

So from time to time I'm getting this error

[image]

I tried to wrap it with `try/catch` block but it didn't work.

```js
try {
    chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId: tabId }, version, function(){
        ...
    })
} catch(e){
    console.log('e', e)
}
```

SO how can I handle this error ?

Answer (score 1):

You handle the error by checking the value of `chrome.runtime.lastError` in the callback function that you passed to `chrome.debugger.attach()`

```
if (!attachedTabIds.includes(tabId)) {
    chrome.debugger.attach(
        {tabId: tabId},
        version,
        function() {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.log("Error");
                console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Success");
            }
        }
    );
}
```

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#property-lastError

> lastError
>
> This will be defined during an API method callback if there was an error